# counting the number of times a recursive function is called

Tags: php, function

I need to know how many times a recursive function is called within the function. This is my function:

```
function structure($x) {
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT `parent_id` FROM `categories` WHERE `categories_id`=$x");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
$cat = $result['parent_id'];
if($cat !=0) {
    structure($cat);
}
echo $cat.' >';
}
```

I have tried adding a counter, e.g. $i=0, then $i++, but it will of course revert back to the $i=0 every time the function is called. I have tried adding arrays, and counting the arrays, but of course it has to set a new array, $i=array(), every time the function is called.

The one way I can think might work is if I set the array or counter outside of the function, but I don't know if its possible to call a variable in a function that is outside the function.

Any ideas on how to call a variable outside a function or even a better way to count the times the function is called?

Comment: pass the counter as the function parameter or use the global variable for the counting

Comment: You can use a variable declared outside of a function by declaring it as `GLOBAL`

Comment: declare a global varible that should do the trick

Comment: don't use "global", the right answer is to use an additional parameter. I really can't believe that "global" is still suggested as a good solution :(

Comment: For those curious about why not to use global http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Answer (score 19):

Option 1: pass in a variable by reference

```
function structure($cat, &$counter) {
    $counter++;
    ...
}

structure('foo', $counter);

echo $counter;
```

Option 2: use a `static` variable

```
function structure($cat) {
    static $counter = 0;
    echo ++$counter;
    ...
}
```

Option 3: use a `global` variable (no no!)

```
$counter = 0;

function structure($cat) {
    global $counter;
    $counter++;
    ...
}
```

Option 4: use a closure

```
$counter = 0;

$structure = function ($cat) use (&$counter) {
    $counter++;
    ...
}

$structure('foo');
echo $counter;
```

Comment: Note: for your use case, option 1 is the most realistic and commonly used one.

Comment: for option 1 I get an error:
 Warning: Missing argument 2 for structure(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\customers\msl\test-nav3.php on line 11 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\customers\msl\test-nav3.php on line 4

Comment: @Source Then you did not include the second variable in a call...! Most likely in a recursive call.

Comment: function structure($x, &$count) {
 $qry = mysql_query("SELECT `parent_id` FROM `categories` WHERE `categories_id`=$x");
 $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
 $cat = $result['parent_id'];
 $count ++;
 if($cat !=0) {
  structure($cat);
 }
 echo $cat.' >';
}


echo structure(22, $count);
echo $count;

Comment: @Source: oops, it's right there: `structure($cat);` right in the middle! Change it so it contains `structure($cat, $count);`.

Answer (score 4):

You can add another parameter to your recursive function, which will serve as a counter:

```
function structure($x, $cnt) {
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT `parent_id` FROM `categories` WHERE `categories_id`=$x");
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
    $cat = $result['parent_id'];
    if($cat !=0) {
        structure($cat, $cnt++);
    }
    echo $cat.' >';
}
```

or you could use a global variable.

Comment: but how do I return the total though, as it will have echo $cnt in each function. I only want the total, not an incremental count.

Comment: when you decide to exit completely from the recursive function (from the recursive logic, not only from that iteration), then use echo

Comment: echo structure($x, $cnt); --> gives you the total

Answer (score 2):

My usual solution to this problem when I'm faced with it is to add a counter variable as an extra parameter, e.g.

```
function structure($x, $i=0) {
    ...
    structure($nextX, ++$i);
    ...
}
```

This has the benefit that the original call to `structure` does not require you to specify the counter, and such can still be called as `structure($x);`

Answer (score 0):

Define the counter-Variable outside the function as `GLOBAL` and increase inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

use `static` variables. such as

```
function structure($x) {
     static $counter = 0;
    /* your code */
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: That's `function foo($bar) { static $count = 0; $count++; /* blah blah blah */ $count--; }`. Note the placing of the increment and the existence of the decrement.

Comment: @michaelb958 I can't understand what exactly you mean

Comment: `$count` is meant to be 1 if you called the function, 2 if the function called itself, 3 if the function called itself which is now calling itself, and in general `N` if the function with `$count` `N-1` called it. Your code doesn't do that (well, it kinda does, but we want `$count` to be left at 0 when the final return occurs).

Comment: @michaelb958 I'm not exactly writing code here. I have suggested how to increment value within a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

Use references :

```
function structure($x, &$i) {
    $i++;
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT `parent_id` FROM `categories` WHERE `categories_id`=$x");
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
    $cat = $result['parent_id'];
    if($cat !=0) {
        structure($cat, $i);
    }
    echo $cat.' >';
}



$i = 0;
structure($var,$i);
var_dump($i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have number of options.

The simplest are:

- you can add static variable
- you can pass counter as additional variable.

Less obvious and more complicated solutions may include using Registry and/or Singleton patterns.

Comment: but how can I stop it echoing every increment for every time the function is called?

Comment: @deceze gave a very elegant solution - closure. It seems to be the best solution.

Comment: Cannot add formatted code to comment, so I'll add it to answer.

Comment: I've updated the most accurate answer of @deceze, so when(if?) he will approve it, you'll see the full solution there.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
// function Counter 
$cnt = 0;

function structure($x) {


global $cnt;

$cnt += 1;

$qry = mysql_query("SELECT `parent_id` FROM `categories` WHERE `categories_id`=$x");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
$cat = $result['parent_id'];
if($cat !=0) {
    structure($cat);
}
echo $cat.' >';
}
```